# How to use variable in variable in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

I have two variables -

```
regex="<version>[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*[^<]*<\/version>"
updated_regex="<version>${main_version}\.${feature_version}\.${patch_version}${tag}<\/version>"
```

Which i want to use in following command -

```
sed "s/$regex/$updated_regex/1" pom.xml
```

But it is not working as the regex and variables are not being evaluated or substituted in my command.

Comment: The variables in `updated_regex` are expanded as soon as you run the line assigning the `updated_regex` variable, NOT when you run the `sed` line.

Comment: it is prompting  to wait for 5 mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already said in my comment, when you run the line

```bsh
updated_regex="<version>${main_version}\.${feature_version}\.${patch_version}${tag}<\/version>"
```

the variable `updated_regex` will be assigned that string, where all those variables will be expanded at the moment you run this line.

When you run the `sed` line this string will be used, but the variables inside the top line won't be expanded again. So the solution is to use the following:

```bsh
regex="<version>[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*[^<]*<\/version>"
sed "s/$regex/<version>${main_version}\.${feature_version}\.${patch_version}${tag}<\/version>/1" pom.xml
```